# Proof of a simple formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove the following equation:

$$-(B+C)\dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r} + B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r} + C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}=\dfrac{B-C}{2}\dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r}$$

This question is from my previous post in physics {while substituting (A-03) in (A-02) to get equation 21(in question)} at:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257127/confusion-in-maxwells-derivation-of-amperes-force-law-part-ii

Comment: Multiplying everything on LHS and simplifying, we get:$$-B\dfrac{l'\eta}{r} -C\dfrac{m'\xi}{r}$$. Now how do I get the RHS from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{m'\xi}r=b$ and $\frac{l'\eta}r=c$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
-(B+C)\dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r} + B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r} + C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}&=&\dfrac{B-C}{2}\dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r}\\
-(B+C)(b+c)+ Bb + Cb&=&\dfrac{B-C}{2}(b+c)\\
-Bb-Cb-Bc-Cc+Bb+Cc&=&\frac{Bb}2+\frac{Bc}2-\frac{Cb}2-\frac{Cc}2\\
-Bc-Cb&=&\frac{Bb}2+\frac{Bc}2-\frac{Cb}2-\frac{Cc}2\\
0&=&\frac{Bb}2+\frac{3Bc}2+\frac{Cb}2-\frac{Cc}2\\
\frac{Cc}2&=&\frac{Bb}2+\frac{3Bc}2+\frac{Cb}2
\end{eqnarray*}
So, you need the last equality to get what you want. By multiplying both sides by $2r$ you get
$$Cl'\eta=Bm'\xi+3Bl'\eta+Cm'\xi$$
or 
$$C(l'\eta-m'\xi)=B(m'\xi+3l'\eta)$$
or 
$$l'\eta(C-3B)=m'\xi(B+C)$$